# Capture live window data

Tags: r

I would like to capture image data (like red, green, blue values for pixels) for a specified application window, and to do so periodically (like every 100 milliseconds) in R for the purpose of making a game bot. Ideally, I want the data to be directly read into a dataframe so it can immediately be used as input to a learning algorithm.

What are some suggested ways to do this? I am using R on Ubuntu linux.

Comment: Is it correct to assume your data is stored in the form of say an image on your computer? And this image may change, say every 100 milliseconds, Or do you have lots of different images? Or is it not stored as an image, but rather an excel filed? Or.... you see where this is going.....

Comment: The data should be in the form of an image. I don't intend to 'store' anything as in save it to a file to disk, but if this is inevitable then I would prefer your first scenario where the same image changes rather than storing many images.

Comment: Maybe there is another way, one way would be to store this image, read it into r, do what analysis u want, then overwrite the image etc... Although, this doesn't sound fast enough for your application. If you can store the images as a data frame, this will increase speed, but again unsure of specifics in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you would need to have a way to capture a screenshot and save it to a (temporary) file. The best way I found (using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194427/what-is-the-terminal-command-to-take-a-screenshot) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/75614/take-a-screen-shot-from-command-line-in-windows)) is using [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/index.php).

If you have ImageMagick installed, you can use the following R function/skript to capture the screen, load the data and plot the data in R (you might want to tweak the arguments based on your desired resolution etc.).

Lastly, if you want to do more with the image, I recommend the [`imager`](https://dahtah.github.io/imager/imager.html) package.

## Skript and load the image into R

```r
library(imager) # for loading and plotting of the PNG file
library(glue)   # for string parsing

capture_screen <- function(file = "screenshot.png") {
  system(glue("import -window root -resize 2560x1440 -delay 200 {file}"))
  invisible(file)
}

file <- capture_screen()

shot <- load.image(file)

shot
#> Image. Width: 2560 pix Height: 1440 pix Depth: 1 Colour channels: 3

shot[1:10, 1:10, ]
#> , , 1
#> 
#>            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
#>  [1,] 0.3440452 0.3385519 0.3357443 0.3331807 0.3284199 0.3248798
#>  [2,] 0.3440452 0.3385519 0.3357443 0.3331807 0.3284199 0.3248798
#>  [3,] 0.3440452 0.3385519 0.3357443 0.3331807 0.3284199 0.3248798
#>  [4,] 0.3440452 0.3385519 0.3357443 0.3331807 0.3284199 0.3248798
#>  [5,] 0.3440452 0.3385519 0.3357443 0.3331807 0.3284199 0.3248798
#>  [6,] 0.3440452 0.3385519 0.3357443 0.3331807 0.3284199 0.3248798
#>  [7,] 0.3440452 0.3385519 0.3357443 0.3331807 0.3284199 0.3248798
#>  [8,] 0.3440452 0.3385519 0.3357443 0.3331807 0.3284199 0.3248798
#>  [9,] 0.3440452 0.3385519 0.3357443 0.3331807 0.3284199 0.3248798
#> [10,] 0.3440452 0.3385519 0.3357443 0.3331807 0.3284199 0.3248798
#>            [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     [,10]
#>  [1,] 0.3221790 0.3186389 0.3138781 0.3112993
#>  [2,] 0.3221790 0.3186389 0.3138781 0.3112993
#>  [3,] 0.3221790 0.3186389 0.3138781 0.3112993
#>  [4,] 0.3221790 0.3186389 0.3138781 0.3112993
#>  [5,] 0.3221790 0.3186389 0.3138781 0.3112993
#>  [6,] 0.3221790 0.3186389 0.3138781 0.3112993
#>  [7,] 0.3221790 0.3186389 0.3138781 0.3112993
#>  [8,] 0.3221790 0.3186389 0.3138781 0.3112840
#>  [9,] 0.3221790 0.3186389 0.3138018 0.3109636
#> [10,] 0.3221942 0.3185931 0.3136797 0.3123674
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
#>  [1,] 0.3319905 0.3292439 0.3244831 0.3209583 0.3181506 0.3152209
#>  [2,] 0.3319905 0.3292439 0.3244831 0.3209583 0.3181506 0.3152209
#>  [3,] 0.3319905 0.3292439 0.3244831 0.3209583 0.3181506 0.3152209
#>  [4,] 0.3319905 0.3292439 0.3244831 0.3209583 0.3181506 0.3152209
#>  [5,] 0.3319905 0.3292439 0.3244831 0.3209583 0.3181506 0.3152209
#>  [6,] 0.3319905 0.3292439 0.3244831 0.3209583 0.3181506 0.3152209
#>  [7,] 0.3319905 0.3292439 0.3244831 0.3209583 0.3181506 0.3152209
#>  [8,] 0.3319905 0.3292439 0.3244831 0.3209583 0.3181506 0.3152209
#>  [9,] 0.3319905 0.3292439 0.3244831 0.3209583 0.3181506 0.3152209
#> [10,] 0.3319905 0.3292439 0.3244831 0.3209583 0.3181506 0.3152209
#>            [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     [,10]
#>  [1,] 0.3121691 0.3096513 0.3048905 0.3013504
#>  [2,] 0.3121691 0.3096513 0.3048905 0.3013504
#>  [3,] 0.3121691 0.3096513 0.3048905 0.3013504
#>  [4,] 0.3121691 0.3096513 0.3048905 0.3013504
#>  [5,] 0.3121691 0.3096513 0.3048905 0.3013504
#>  [6,] 0.3121691 0.3096513 0.3048905 0.3013504
#>  [7,] 0.3121691 0.3096513 0.3048905 0.3013504
#>  [8,] 0.3121691 0.3096513 0.3048905 0.3013352
#>  [9,] 0.3121691 0.3096513 0.3048600 0.3008164
#> [10,] 0.3121996 0.3095750 0.3045701 0.3070420
#> 
#> , , 3
#> 
#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]
#>  [1,] 0.300679 0.2975357 0.2945907 0.2916915 0.2887007 0.2857862 0.2828412
#>  [2,] 0.300679 0.2975357 0.2945907 0.2916915 0.2887007 0.2857862 0.2828412
#>  [3,] 0.300679 0.2975357 0.2945907 0.2916915 0.2887007 0.2857862 0.2828412
#>  [4,] 0.300679 0.2975357 0.2945907 0.2916915 0.2887007 0.2857862 0.2828412
#>  [5,] 0.300679 0.2975357 0.2945907 0.2916915 0.2887007 0.2857862 0.2828412
#>  [6,] 0.300679 0.2975357 0.2945907 0.2916915 0.2887007 0.2857862 0.2828412
#>  [7,] 0.300679 0.2975357 0.2945907 0.2916915 0.2887007 0.2857862 0.2828412
#>  [8,] 0.300679 0.2975357 0.2945907 0.2916915 0.2887007 0.2857862 0.2828412
#>  [9,] 0.300679 0.2975357 0.2945907 0.2916915 0.2887007 0.2857862 0.2828412
#> [10,] 0.300679 0.2975357 0.2945907 0.2916915 0.2887007 0.2857862 0.2829328
#>            [,8]      [,9]     [,10]
#>  [1,] 0.2799268 0.2769360 0.2740215
#>  [2,] 0.2799268 0.2769360 0.2740215
#>  [3,] 0.2799268 0.2769360 0.2740215
#>  [4,] 0.2799268 0.2769360 0.2740215
#>  [5,] 0.2799268 0.2769360 0.2740215
#>  [6,] 0.2799268 0.2769360 0.2740215
#>  [7,] 0.2799268 0.2769360 0.2740215
#>  [8,] 0.2799268 0.2769360 0.2740215
#>  [9,] 0.2799268 0.2769207 0.2734569
#> [10,] 0.2796063 0.2775616 0.2841840
```

## Plot the image

```r
plot(shot)
```

[image]

```r
# render only a subset
imsub(shot, y <= 200, y >= 100, x <= 500, x >= 200) %>% plot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

## Edit

If you only want to load the data without the `screenshot.png` file, you can also do

```r
capture_screen2 <- function(xmin = 0, xmax = Inf, ymin = 0, ymax = Inf) {
  tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
  system(glue("import -window root -resize 2560x1440 -delay 200 {tmp}"))

  img <- load.image(tmp)
  a <- try(unlink(tmp))
  imsub(img, x >= xmin, x <= xmax, y >= ymin, y <= ymax)
}

shot <- capture_screen2()
```

## Edit 2: Speed Issues

I did some [benchmarking](https://gist.github.com/DavZim/8602875652752f293bc7224cba1014d6) of the speed of the code, the fastest option is to use [`scrot`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/scrot.1.html) (`sudo apt install scrot` on Ubuntu) in combination with the [`png`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/png/index.html) package:

```r
system(glue::glue("scrot --silent screenshot.png"))
img <- png::readPNG("screenshot.png")
dim(img)
```